# Custom linux pcie driver MSI interrupts

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing a custom linux PCIe driver for an embedded device. For this purpose I need to enable multiple MSI vectors. When I use the function `pci_enable_msi(pdev)` the code works properly. However when I use `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev,4);` the function returns 1 meaning it can only allocate 1 interrupt. If I use `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev,32);` the function returns 16 upon which I use `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev,16);` but the return value is again 1.

I tried to check the return value for all possible arguments and the result was as below:

```
for(i=2;i<33;i++)
    {
       ret = pci_enable_msi_block(pdev,i);
       printk(KERN_DEBUG "For request i=%d the return value is=%d\n",i, ret);
    }
```

```
[   89.421184] For request i=2 the return value is=1
[   89.421196] For request i=3 the return value is=1
[   89.421208] For request i=4 the return value is=1
[   89.421220] For request i=5 the return value is=1
[   89.421232] For request i=6 the return value is=1
[   89.421243] For request i=7 the return value is=1
[   89.421255] For request i=8 the return value is=1
[   89.421266] For request i=9 the return value is=1
[   89.421278] For request i=10 the return value is=1
[   89.421290] For request i=11 the return value is=1
[   89.421301] For request i=12 the return value is=1
[   89.421313] For request i=13 the return value is=1
[   89.421325] For request i=14 the return value is=1
[   89.421336] For request i=15 the return value is=1
[   89.421348] For request i=16 the return value is=1
[   89.421353] For request i=17 the return value is=16
[   89.421359] For request i=18 the return value is=16
[   89.421364] For request i=19 the return value is=16
[   89.421369] For request i=20 the return value is=16
[   89.421374] For request i=21 the return value is=16
[   89.421380] For request i=22 the return value is=16
[   89.421385] For request i=23 the return value is=16
[   89.421390] For request i=24 the return value is=16
[   89.421395] For request i=25 the return value is=16
[   89.421401] For request i=26 the return value is=16
[   89.421406] For request i=27 the return value is=16
[   89.421411] For request i=28 the return value is=16
[   89.421416] For request i=29 the return value is=16
[   89.421422] For request i=30 the return value is=16
[   89.421427] For request i=31 the return value is=16
[   89.421432] For request i=32 the return value is=16
```

the function call is successful (returns 0) only when `pci_enable_msi_block(pdev,1)` is used.

I have also tried to use the `pci_enable_msi_exact` and `pci_enable_msi_range` functions but then the code does not compile and gives an implicit function declaration error.

Kindly provide suggestions on how to resolve this issue so that I can use four MSI vectors.

Comment: Did you try to put some `printk` into [pci_enable_msi_block](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pci/msi.c?v=3.12#L829) to understand what is failing?

Comment: "Did you try to pot some printk into pci_enable_msi_block to understand what is failing?" can you tell how i should do that as this function is from the built in linux driver?

Comment: Are you using a Specific Vendor Kernel?

Comment: Yes it is from ti arago project

Comment: You are on an embedded system. I supposed you have recompiled your kernel source code for your platform. At least to create your specific DTB files, if kernel support them.

Comment: Ok, I found out [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24332667/using-pci-enable-msi-block). Could be a kernel bug...

Comment: yes i did update the dtb file

Comment: If you did that, you'd modify other source code also.

Comment: yes most probably if this is so how can i correct it, i am new to linux

Comment: Ask to your vendor support. I'm sorry, I'm not a TI expert.

Comment: i did not make any changes to the source code, the steps i followed were to install the linux devkit and then upload the kernel file .bin and the device  tree dtb to the device

Comment: Take a look [HERE](http://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/linux/f/354/p/424995/1530132). Maybe your case.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the same problem i am having however the solution they present to call pci_enable_msi_block multiple times seems incorrect as it will only update the pdev->irq with the interrupt number whereas the requirement is to allocate pdev->irq+1 to pdev->irq+count -1 if my understanding of pci_enable_msi_block is correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check your configuration registers to determine how many MSI are available to be allocated. The PCIe device determines this.

You will need to probe configuration registers. Take the LSB of the DWORD to obtain the command register. This controls legacy interrupts. Take the MSB of address 0x50 to determine the message control. This controls the MSI.

Make sure that legacy interrupts are disabled and bus master enabled in the command register. Use 0x50 (MSB) to determine how many MSI can be allocated. bits 4:6 determine this and bit 0 enables MSI.

I ran into a similar problem but it turned out that my endpoint was only capable of a single MSI and I was unable to change that due to vendor limitations.